# Tricky update values from one dataset with another using Pandas (with conditions)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I'd like to create a new dataset (df3) by updating values based on the [area] and [Date] column match.

Here are the two datasets. df1 contains the update, df2 contains the file that will be updated with df1 data. **If there is no date or area match, the bb, aa and cc values will be 0.**

**DATA**

df1

```
Date        area        bb  aa  cc  
7/1/2023    Australia   30  0   0   
8/1/2023    Australia   50  0   0   
4/1/2024    Australia   0   0   12  
6/1/2024    Australia   30  0   24  
9/1/2024    Australia   0   0   24  
11/1/2024   Australia   0   0   24  
2/1/2025    Australia   35  0   0
```

df2

```
Date        area        bb  aa  cc  stat
03/1/2023   Australia   5   5   5   yes
06/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
07/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   yes
08/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   yes
09/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
10/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
02/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   no
03/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   yes
04/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   yes
05/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   no
06/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   no
9/1/2024    Australia   10  10  10  yes
11/1/2024   Australia   10  11  20  yes
2/1/2025    Australia   35  0   0   yes
1/1/2026    Malaysia    7   9   8   no
```

**DESIRED**

We see that the new dataset values are replaced with df1 values.(look at dates: 7/1/2023, 8/1/2023 etc.) If df1 does not contain df2 values, aa, bb, cc are set to 0.    (look at 3/1/2023 and 1/1/2026 values)

df3

```
Date        area        bb  aa  cc  stat
03/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   yes
06/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
07/1/2023   Australia   30  0   0   yes
08/1/2023   Australia   50  0   0   yes
09/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
10/1/2023   Australia   0   0   0   no
02/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   no
03/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   yes
04/1/2024   Australia   0   0   12  yes
05/1/2024   Australia   0   0   0   no
06/1/2024   Australia   30  0   24  no
9/1/2024    Australia   0   0   24  yes
11/1/2024   Australia   0   0   24  yes
2/1/2025    Australia   35  0   0   yes
1/1/2026    Malaysia    0   0   0   no
```

**Doing**

I think it is best to use a join or merge- however, some of the data is not being replaced

```
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])
df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"])

df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=["area", "date"], how="right").filter(regex=r".*(?<!_y)$")
df3.columns = df3.columns.str.split("_").str[0]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am still researching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# ensure same data
# you could also keep the strings and pad the zeros
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

keys = ['Date', 'area']
# align df1 on df2's keys and fill with 0s
df3 = (df2[keys+['stat']]
 .merge(df1, on=keys, how='left')
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 [df2.columns] # restore original order
)
```

output:

```
         Date       area  bb  aa  cc stat
0  2023-03-01  Australia   0   0   0  yes
1  2023-06-01  Australia   0   0   0   no
2  2023-07-01  Australia  30   0   0  yes
3  2023-08-01  Australia  50   0   0  yes
4  2023-09-01  Australia   0   0   0   no
5  2023-10-01  Australia   0   0   0   no
6  2024-02-01  Australia   0   0   0   no
7  2024-03-01  Australia   0   0   0  yes
8  2024-04-01  Australia   0   0  12  yes
9  2024-05-01  Australia   0   0   0   no
10 2024-06-01  Australia  30   0  24   no
11 2024-09-01  Australia   0   0  24  yes
12 2024-11-01  Australia   0   0  24  yes
13 2025-02-01  Australia  35   0   0  yes
14 2026-01-01   Malaysia   0   0   0   no
```

Comment: ok I will try this thank you - @mozway - please could you tell me how you became an expert on Python (sources) thanks

Comment: The answer might disappoint you but I simply used it a lot and read many pages of documentations in detail. There is no magic trick, you just need to practice a lot ;)

Comment: ok I will do this - documentation, as in the Pandas.org documentation?

Comment: Yes, [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html), [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/), [`python`](https://docs.python.org/3/) and many more

Comment: ok thank you this worked - maybe you can do tutorial - thank you! @mozway

Comment: If there are multiple columns, could I just add these? df3 = (df2[keys+['stat', 'stat1','stat2']]   @mozway

Comment: Yes, add here the columns unique to `df2`